# Are there modern commentaries on Plato's Gorgias?

Tags: plato

I would like some advice on editions of Plato's work.

In particular, which commented edition of Plato's Gorgias is considered more authoritative, or at least most often referred to students by scholars of Plato?

I am looking for works in English, but reference to works in other languages is welcome too.

Comment: I would suggest rewording your question as providing references with a short comment at best, because as it stands it sounds pretty much opinion-based.

Comment: You can see the *Introduction* by Eric Robertson Dodds to his edition of [Gorgias](https://books.google.it/books?id=9XjiHXkQ0DYC) and Seth Benardete, [The Rhetoric of Morality and Philosophy: Plato's Gorgias and Phaedrus](https://books.google.it/books?id=tO-vB5B9ff4C&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: @Philip Klöcking  How so? I am not stating any opinion, do I?

Comment: The problem is not wether *you* are stating opinions in your question, but that you *ask for* opinions, i.e. that answers have to be opinion-based.

Comment: I just thought this might be useful to some scholars of the Greek classics, Plato in particular: https://archive.org/details/gorgiasss00platuoft/page/n5 http://www.caas-cw.org/archive/lodge.html